# New to WordPress reset password

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Hello Stackoverflow users,

I'm working on an eCommerce website and when I get to the reset password I get redirected back to the checkout page and have been trying to fix this issue for days and still no luck. I was wondering if there is a fix for this issue. I tried a dummy email to see and no redirect to email to change the password and this bug is been an issue. if anyone can help I do apricate it. If you want to test it here's the link https://genigeek.com/my-account/customer-reset-password/

```html
 <?php
/**
 * Customer Reset Password email
 *
 * This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/emails/customer-reset-password.php.
 *
 * HOWEVER, on occasion WooCommerce will need to update template files and you
 * (the theme developer) will need to copy the new files to your theme to
 * maintain compatibility. We try to do this as little as possible, but it does
 * happen. When this occurs the version of the template file will be bumped and
 * the readme will list any important changes.
 *
 * @see https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/
 * @package WooCommerce\Templates\Emails
 * @version 4.0.0
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly.
}

?>

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_email_header', $email_heading, $email ); ?>

<?php /* translators: %s: Customer username */ ?>
<p><?php printf( esc_html__( 'Hi %s,', 'woocommerce' ), esc_html( $user_login ) ); ?></p>
<?php /* translators: %s: Store name */ ?>
<p><?php printf( esc_html__( 'Someone has requested a new password for the following account on %s:', 'woocommerce' ), esc_html( wp_specialchars_decode( get_option( 'blogname' ), ENT_QUOTES ) ) ); ?></p>
<?php /* translators: %s: Customer username */ ?>
<p><?php printf( esc_html__( 'Username: %s', 'woocommerce' ), esc_html( $user_login ) ); ?></p>
<p><?php esc_html_e( 'If you didn\'t make this request, just ignore this email. If you\'d like to proceed:', 'woocommerce' ); ?></p>
<p>
    <a class="link" href="<?php echo esc_url( add_query_arg( array( 'key' => $reset_key, 'id' => $user_id ), wc_get_endpoint_url( 'customer-reset-password', '', wc_get_page_permalink( 'myaccount' ) ) ) ); ?>"><?php // phpcs:ignore ?>
        <?php esc_html_e( 'Click here to reset your password', 'woocommerce' ); ?>
    </a>
</p>

<?php
/**
 * Show user-defined additional content - this is set in each email's settings.
 */
if ( $additional_content ) {
    echo wp_kses_post( wpautop( wptexturize( $additional_content ) ) );
}

do_action( 'woocommerce_email_footer', $email );
```

Comment: Did you clear cache ?

Comment: I have not I'll try and see